# Dynamic Layout creation

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an activity which will show the contents downloaded from server. Suppose it contains six items and each item contains an image and a text for description. I have created a custom layout for this which contains six layouts. everything works fine but problem is in some item, description is large and in some item its small. So in layout it shows whitespace and at some place it cuts the part of description(because its defined statically in xml). I want to create it dynamically so that i will calculate each item length and based on that dynamically create the layouts. It seems difficult but i have to achieve it for removing white spaces.I need to calculate the content size and screen size and accordingly have to take decision for rendering layout. Any suggestion how can I achieve it, any link where I can find the similar solution? Or is there any component already present in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope u've searched bit more google have answers https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=creating%20dynamic%20layout%20android

Comment: Atleast show us ur xml layouts

Comment: learn about ListView